# Armstrong number code in Java is not working right

Tags: java

I am completely new to Java and am writing code to check whether a number is an Armstrong number or not in the range 0 to 999.

Please tell me what is wrong. When run on command prompt, it repeatedly prints:

> 1 is the count

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Armstrong
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int n = i;
            int count =0;

            while(n > 0)
            {
                int mod = n % 10;
                n = n / 10;
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(+count+ "is the count");

            for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
            {   
                int val = i % 10;
                i= i / 10;
                sum = val * val * val + sum;
            }
            if (sum == i)
            {
                System.out.println( +i+ "is an Armstrong number");
            }       
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by indenting the code correctly, to make it readable.

Comment: Did you mean to do i = i/10 in your second for loop? Do you also mean to set count equal to 0 for each iteration of your first for loop?

Answer (score 2):

> An Armstrong number is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits.

For starters, you always raise the digits to the power of 3, so your calculation can only work for `i` between `100` and `999`.

Second, you are changing `i` within your inner loop, so the comparison at the end `if (sum==i)` will fail, since sum should be compared to the original `i`.

Next, you don't reset `sum` to `0` in each iteration of `i`.

You also skip one of the digits.

This seems to work :

```
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) { // start at 100
        sum = 0; // clear the sum in each iteration
        int n = i;
        int count = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            int mod = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            count++;
        }
        n = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) { // iterate over all the digits

            int val = n % 10;
            n = n / 10; // don't change i
            sum = val * val * val + sum;

        }
        if (sum == i) {
            System.out.println(i + " is an Armstrong number");
        }
    }
```

This returns :

```
153 is an Armstrong number
370 is an Armstrong number
371 is an Armstrong number
407 is an Armstrong number
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run three loops. You can do it simpler that way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int currNumber = i;
        int sum = 0;

        while(currNumber != 0)
        {
            int mod = currNumber % 10;
            sum = sum + mod * mod * mod;
            currNumber = currNumber / 10;
        }

        if (i == sum) {
            System.out.println(i + " is an Armstrong number");
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Print Armstrong number in java

```
public class CalculatArmstrong 
{   

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    for(int i=0;i<=2000;i++)
    {

        int number=i;
        int n=number;
        int rem;
        int arms=0;

        while(number>0)
        {
            rem=number%10;

            arms=arms+rem*rem*rem;

            number=number/10;

        }


        if(n==arms)
        {

            System.out.println(n);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You don't explain at all what your code do. Please learn [how to write an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Now I Correct this @Mistalis. Thank you